# Ruby Restart Array Loop

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to restart an array loop in ruby once the entire array has been iterated through.

I've found that the `retry` method will not work for this. Code below:

```
letters = ["A","B","C"]

letters.each do |letter|
  puts letter
  if letter == letters.last
    puts "that was the last letter"
    #restart the array from A again (I'd like it to continue looping infinitely)
  end
  sleep 1
end
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `cycle`.

```
letters.cycle do |letter|
  ...
end
```

Comment: An alternative is `letters.size.times.cycle { |i| ....letters[i].... }`. This may be useful if one needs to know the letter offset in the block.

Comment: @CarySwoveland or `letters.each_with_index.cycle { |l, i| ... }` / `letters.cycle.with_index { |l, i| ... }`

Comment: @Stefan, of possible interest: `letters.each_with_index.cycle.first(5) #=> [["A", 0], ["B", 1], ["C", 2], ["A", 0], ["B", 1]]`, whereas `letters.cycle.with_index.first(5) #=>  [["A", 0], ["B", 1], ["C", 2], ["A", 3], ["B", 4]]`.

Comment: The latter along with `divmod` is probably most versatile - it gives you loop count, element index and total count.

Answer (score 5):

Just put your `each` loop into another loop:

```
loop do
  letters.each do |letter|
    puts letter
    sleep 1
  end
  puts "that was the last letter"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(0..Float::INFINITY).each do |i|
  puts letters[i % letters.size] 
  puts "Whew! That was the last letter, so it's time to start over." \
    if ((i+1) %letters.size).zero?
end
  # A
  # B
  # C
  # Whew! That was the last letter, so it's time to start over.
  # A
  # B
  # C
  # Whew! That was the last letter, so it's time to start over.
  # A
  # B
  # ...
```

Comment: Starting with Ruby 2.0, you can also write `0.step { |i| ... }`

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

From Ruby1.9 `retry` can only be used inside a `begin/rescue` block

What you are trying to do can be done like this:

```
letters = ["A","B","C"]
begin
  letters.each do |letter|
    puts letter
    if letter == letters.last
      puts "that was the last letter"
      #restart the array from A again (I'd like it to continue looping infinitely)
      raise
    end
  end
rescue
  sleep 1
  retry
end
```

Take note of the `raise` keyword after the comment which causes the code to go into `rescue` and then `sleep` and `retry`

Another option would be to use `cycle` which is more clean and elegant